# Missing modules when debugging Python code in Emacs

Tags: python, debugging, environment

For a number of reasons - the main one being that **Emacs is amazing!** - I am trying to do all my Python development at work in Emacs instead of Pycharm, which I was using previously.

The one component I have not been able to get running right in Emacs is the debugger. I have been trying to use `pdb` in emacs to debug the application I am working on, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get `pdb` to find all the necessary modules. Instead, when I run my `__main__.py` file through pdb, I get a bunch of import errors because it can't find the modules for the project. If I manually add the appropriate paths to `sys.paths` and then import the modules one by one from the interactive pdb prompt, this works, but obviously is not the right solution.

In the Pycharm debugger there are two options: "add content roots to PYTHONPATH" and "add source roots to PYTHONPATH", which configure this stuff automatically. My issue is that I haven't figured out how to configure equivalent options in Emacs - i.e., I am not sure how/where to set PYTHONPATH so that `pdb` within Emacs recognizes it. I have tried setting it a few different was in my Emacs config, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What about `(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "/the/python/path")` in your init file?

Comment: That did it actually! This was one of the first solutions that I tried, but it turned out I had entered the wrong path! If you put this as an answer I will accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how/where to set PYTHONPATH

To inform Emacs about your PYTHONPATH, just edit your init file and add this line:

`(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "/the/python/path")`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Where can I find my python path, do I need to restart emacs before setenv starts working? I have tried a couple of paths already (from ```which python``` in the terminal or from just importing modules in an interactive shell and getting part of the module address, but I've had no success so far)

Comment: @LeoAzevedo The value returned by `which python` is not your PYTHONPATH. Open a terminal, and type `echo $PYTHONPATH`. Replace "/the/python/path" in my answer, by the printed value. Let me know.

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH returns nothing literally in my Terminal. However, which python returns Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3